# Fluent Validation with dynamic object in c#

Tags: c#, azure-functions, fluentvalidation

I want to use fluent validation to validate the http request in Azure functions. My object is dynamic type.Can I create a fluent validation validator for my dynamic object?

Actually I am receiving different types of object based on the one parameter "EventType" in the request body in this azure function so that's why i have to use dynamic object.

```
[FunctionName("ReceiveEvent")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log,
            [Inject] IAzureBlobStorage azureBlobStorage
            )
        {
            _log = log;

            _log.Info("ReceiveEvent HTTP trigger function started processing request.");

            _log.Info($"Pushing Events to Azure Blob on storage account :-{CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureWebJobsStorage")}");

            dynamic data;
            // Get request body
            try
            {
                data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var requestData = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                _telemetry.TrackEvent("InvalidRequest",
                    new Dictionary<string, string> { { "RequestData", requestData } });
                _log.Error("Invalid Request", e);
                var error = new NotificationResult { ResultType = ResultType.Failure, Message = "Please pass valid event in the request body", Sample = _eventMapper.SampleRequest };
                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, error);
            }
}
```

Comment: what would you like to validate?

Comment: I want to validate incoming request. actually in the incoming request I my get 17 different type of objects. and these objects based on the one parameter "eventType"

Comment: That exception handler looks wrong.  If there was any exception thrown (even an out of memory exception), you try and read the content as a string?   That's almost guaranteed to throw another exception.

Comment: "I am receiving different types of object in this azure function so that's why i have to use dynamic object" - that doesn't sound like a good reason to use dynamic.

Comment: Create a base type with at least eventype in it.  Read the data as a string. Deserialise to the base type. Then deserialise based on the value of eventtype and call validate on that?

Comment: Another one I've used is have a general type one of who's values is a base 64 string. Deserialise the data then decode the base64 and deserialise based on in eventytpe in the containing type.

Comment: @Tony Do i need to validate after deserialise?

Comment: Good point, not if it's wired up right.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a Validation factory. Try this code:

```
public class GenericValidator
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _validators = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    public void Register<T>(Func<T, bool> validator)
    {
        _validators[typeof(T)] = validator;
    }

    public Func<T, bool> Retrieve<T>()
    {
        if (_validators.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            return (Func<T, bool>)_validators[typeof(T)];
        }
        return t => false;
    }

    public Func<object, bool> Retrieve(Type type)
    {
        Delegate x = (Delegate)this.GetType()
            .GetMethod("Retrieve", new Type[] { })
            .MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(this, null);
        Func<object, bool> y = o => (bool)x.DynamicInvoke(o);
        return y;
    }

    public void Deregister<T>()
    {
        if (_validators.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            _validators.Remove(typeof(T));
        }
    }   
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
var gv = new GenericValidator();
gv.Register<string>(t => t.Length > 3);

string x = "Hello";
var validator = gv.Retrieve<string>();
if (validator(x))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\"{x}\" is valid.");
}

var validator2 = gv.Retrieve(typeof(string));
if (validator2(x))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\"{x}\" is valid.");
}
```

That outputs:

```
"Hello" is valid.
"Hello" is valid.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do someting like:

```
dynamic data = null;

if (data is EventType1)
{
    // Validation logic for EventType1
}
else if (data is EventType2)
{
    // Validation logic for EventType2
}
else
{
    // unknown type
}
```

of course you can also do `switches` if you like that better.

```
dynamic data = null;

switch (data)
{
    case EventType1 _:
        break;
    case EventType2 _:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but is it good to add even switch case for all 17 types of events? These event may increase to 30 in future

Comment: Might be better to use a lookup table/dictionary rather than maintaining 30 different cases.

Comment: @RakeshKumar - Use a dictionary instead - and avoid `dynamic`.